# array is not a data but a container but why does it have a data type?

Tags: javascript, arrays, types

My understanding of the data type is as follows. If we consider a machine like a mill that can take in rice, barley, corn, kidney beans, chickpeas, black beans, etc. So I understand the mill to be the program that processes data such as rice, barley, etc. The data are rice, barley, beans but they differ in types. Rice is of a different type than barley etc.

In javascript, i noticed objects mentioned under data types.

https://javascript.info/types#objects-and-symbols

It makes sense that 23 is data of type number, "cat" is data of type string, true is data of type "boolean" but object seems to be more like a data container rather than a data type. For instance, typeof([]) says it is an object. Now array seems like a data container rather than data and type of a data container doesn't make sense. To me, it makes sense that a data can have a type but a container where we put data having a type is confusing.

So I appreciate if someone can enlighten me. Array seems to be a container and not data and cannot have a type.

I appreciate any guide. Thanks!

Comment: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~cop3014p/lectures/ch9/index.html. Array IS a structured data type.

Comment: everything is an object in Javascript

Comment: @JoshSharkey: Not quite. `1` tries very hard to behave like an object, but isn't (you can't set a property on `1`, for example).

Comment: All data types are nothing more than data containers. The concept of "type" you are thinking of is called a "primitive". In computing a type is a structure with properties. What those properties are determines the type. For example a "rice" type may have properties `rice.calories`, `rice.weight` and `rice.price`. And both `rice` and `barley` may be a subtype of `grain`. Such objects as "rice", "barley" and "beans" can actually be valid data types in javascript, C++ or Java, not just your mill machine

Comment: then maybe a more intuitive term would be data structure type rather than data type. by data type it is easier to take it literally like 12 is data and its type is number. true is data and its type is boolean. with that understanding it is confusing that a container which is not data how can it have data type. so it is confusing that array is not a data so it cannot have a data type. array can contain data like numbers which can have data types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a general, theoretic level, an object consists of data that describes the object, and behaviours that act on that object. Before Object Oriented Programming, data was data, and code was code; if you needed to load some data, and draw it on the screen, chances are those two pieces of code would be in different places of your code base. OOP brings data and behaviour together for better conceptual organisation. It also allows some objects to share behaviour by sorting them into classes (e.g. "barking" is not something that needs to be coded for every dog individually) or by creating object prototypes (same idea, different approach). Furthermore, it allows different objects to specify different ways of performing the same behaviour (e.g. both cats and wolves know about hunting, though they go about it differently).

On a mechanical JavaScript-specific level, "object" is a data structure that can store various values under string keys. It is thus superficially similar to arrays, which again store values, but under integer keys.

However, "value" in JavaScript also includes functions, which is how JS object achieves the first objective (being a repository of related data and code that governs its behaviour). The second objective is achieved by prototypal inheritance:

```js
let Mammal = function() {
}
let typicalMammal = new Mammal();
typicalMammal.legs = 4;
Mammal.prototype = typicalMammal;

let Dog = function() {
};
let typicalDog = new Mammal();
typicalDog.sound = function() { console.log("woof") };
Dog.prototype = typicalDog;

let fido = new Dog();
fido.colour = "yellow";
console.log("Fido:", fido);
fido.sound();
```

The third is also achieved: if we had a cat, we could just tell `happy.sound()` and it would do a "meow". We don't need to know if something is a dog or a cat, just that they know how to make a sound, and dynamic dispatch will do the rest.

It is also of note that when you invoke a function in an object with a dot notation like this, the function is interpreted as "method" - a function that knows which object it is acting on, by setting a special variable `this`. In this case, within the method `sound`, `this` would have the same value as `fido`.

Specifically with arrays, they are a kind of object that knows how to contain multiple values indicated by an integer index, how to be indexed, how to tell its length, how to iterate on its elements etc.

However, note that "variable" is something different entirely. One could conceptualise that variable is a data structure with a name and a value; but you can't typically access variable's name. A variable is not a value itself; you can't put a variable into a data structure, just copy its value there. It is more of a language artifact than a data type.

Comment: please tell why array has a data type called "object". to me data type only makes sense for a data like 2, "cat", true. array to me seems container for data so type of container doesnt make sense.

Comment: `typeof` is funky in JavaScript for historical reasons. Saying that something is an object is not much, as most things in JavaScript are objects. See my second-to-last paragraph. Just like in real world a wardrobe is an object, and a toolbox is a different kind of object, and you can put a toolbox in a wardrobe and a hammer into a toolbox (though hammer is no container)... in JavaScript, a Map is one kind of object, a Set is another kind of object, Array yet another. They are all objects that happen to also be containers. You can put an Array into a Map, and an Integer into an Array...

Comment: ah...so just like a toolbox can be considered a container when we put something in it and it can also be considered an object if we put it in some other container. so that way a container can be a considered data and hence can have a type. if that is correct i am trying to get the picture. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ECMAScript standard defines eight data types, 7 primitive types and Object.

In JavaScript, objects are a collection of properties and property values can be values of any type, for example an object with an attribute of type "number".

```
let obj = { num: 3 }
```

and you can test

```
typeof obj.num
```

will return "number", but

```
typeof obj
```

will return "object" I suppose because inheritance of prototype Object
All objects in JavaScript are descended from Object, all objects inherit methods and properties from Object.prototype.

In your example of an array. In javascript the array variable has a prototype of Array but that's an object that has a prototype of Object.

```
typeof([])
```

I think that's why is returning you "object".

Here are some links about data structures:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: the primitive types like number, string makes sense because they are types of data. it doesnt make sense to me for a container like array to have a data type. 12 is of type number, "cat" is of type string but [] is a container of data. for it to have a data type doesnt make sense. in my understanding data has a type and that type is called data type. container shouldnt have data type. please clear doubts. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has only one data type for containers and it's called "object".

Arrays are containers and so their **data type** is "object". Like arrays there are other kinds of specialist object classes such as "function" (they contain code and are callable), [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [weak sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakSet) for example.

Significantly the JavaScript `typeof`operator does not always return the data type of its operand. This is due to early implementation details of the operator which can not now be changed - and programs have long since adjusted to the actual implementation:

- `typeof null` returns "object". The data type of `null` is "null".
- `typeof function` returns "function". The data type of a function is "object".

> ...variable is a container and is not data

Variables are not so much a container as an identifier of where a value is stored. Variables in JavaScript are weakly typed which means the data type of a value is not determined by the variable (or object property) to which a value has been assigned  but by the internal memory construct used to hold the value. That is to say, type is obtained from the value stored, not the variable used to access it.

#### Object values

An object value stored in a JavaScript variable is some kind of memory **pointer** to a data structure whose location and implementation details are private and only known to the JavaScript engine.

It makes sense to call objects values a data type in JavaScript for the same reason pointers in C have a data type depending on what they point to.  It also explains why if you assign the same "object value" to two variables, they will both then point to the same object data set held at some unknown location in memory.

The major difference with JavaScript object values is that you can't perform pointer arithmetic on them and must rely on  object property notations `object.propertyName` or `object["propertyName"]` to directly access properties of an object.

#### Array objects

JavaScript arrays are objects which use positive integer values, converted to a string, to access array entries being held as string properties of the array object.

Unlike a typed array, index values to access entries of an `Array` object do not have an upper bound nor do they need to be consecutive - memory is not allocated to store entries which have not been set.

**TLDR;**

JavaScript arrays are implemented as associative lookup tables. Their data type is "object" and they inherit properties and methods from `Array.prototype` and `Object.prototype`.

They are called "exotic" objects in ECMAScript standards because they monitor access to see if the property name used represents a non-negative integer and maintain the array object's `length` property if it is.

Early JavaScript documentation went out its way not to mention pointers, presumably to avoid confusing BASIC programmers. Documentation used "object" to mean a data structure, object values were stored as pointers, and the short hand property access operator chosen was `.` instead of the `->` operator for pointer access used in the C language family.

Comment: thanks but i am still not getting satisfactory answer. It makes sense that 12 is a data and it has a type "number". [] seems to be a data structure or a container so it doesnt make sense for it to have a data type like object. please enlighten. thanks!